# How do we get 0.9996 as scale factor in UTM projection. Want this info to perform grid to ground conversion

Tags: utm, scale-factor

I am working on a Site Calibration project that performs grid to ground conversion with some additional calculations. It's almost ready but I am having issue with calculation the scale factor. I am trying to understand how do we get 0.9996 as scale factor in UTM projection unfortunately I can't find what I am looking for, I am quit aware that this is the scaling of central meridian of a zone and it changes as we move away from CM in any direction. I need help in understanding how do we get 0.9996 as scale factor, what calculations do we perform, what parameters do we use.

In Detail Description -->

I have 2 sets of coordinates in UTM, one set was taken form a total station an year ago and another was taken form a DGPS. Now my objective is to calibrate the DGPS device to the total station so that the coordinates get adjusted according to total station survey conditions.

I have used an application for reference to compare if my calibration file is correct and the output from my code is same as the output from the reference application I have used. But the catch is I get same results as long as I am using default origin and scale for calculation which is intersection of equator and CM of the UTM zone (500000, 0) and 0.9996 as scale. I want to change the origin and scale similar to the reference app but the issue is I am unable to calculate the scale according to my new origin. For this I need to know how 0.9996 scale is calculated by default.

UPDATE --->

So now I got a bit of clarity what I am actually trying to implement and I have 2 methods trying to get my desired output but still I am doing something wrong. I am trying to change the default central meridian to a new lat,lon with new scale factor. For reference I have a file that is generated form Trimble Business Center with a custom central meridian and scale factor.

In my Trimble reference file I have following parameters -:

LAT : 30.149715357,
LON : 74.223726831,
Scale : 1.000022371,

The methods that I used to Calculate scale factor in my code >>

METHOD - 1 : I used to following mathematical equation to calculate new scale factor
k = k0 * (1 - ((e^2 * sin^2φ) / (1 - e^2*sin^2φ)^0.5))
Where k0 = 0.9996,
e = 0.0818191908425 [ Eccentricity ],
φ = math.radians(74.223726831) [ Lat in Radians ],

which outputs new scale k = 0.9999077218406625.

METHOD - 2 : I used "pyproj" module in python >>

utm_proj = pyproj.Proj(proj='utm', zone=43, ellps='WGS84')

_, _, _, _, _, k = utm_proj(lon, lat, radians=False, errcheck=True)

k *= k0

which outputs new scale k = 0.9999262234109836.

Using both the methods my results are not matching with the reference file. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Ground distance uses Combined Scale Factor, which is Grid Scale Factor times Elevation Factor. Need more details on what you're trying to do and what didn't work. What software are you using?

Comment: Thank you @Pointdump. I am using Trimble Business Center to calculate the output and match that with output that my code generates for same set of coords. I am aware of combined scale factor but that's not what I am trying to ask. Now both outputs are matching as long as I am taking the CM of UTM zone as origin (500000, 0) and scale factor as 0.9996. I want to change the origin to first ground point in my set but after I'll need to update the scale factor as well which I don't understand how to calculate. If I could understand how 0.9996 is calculated hopefully that'll solve my problem.

Comment: The scale factor at central meridian is a parameter of the projection. If you change central meridian (another parameter) and scale factor at central meridian, coordinates will not be UTM projection. You can choose those parameters at will to create the Transverse Mercator projection you want. If you want to know the scale factor at any point for a defined Transverse Mercator projection, there are more or less simple formulas, of lesser or greater precision. But there are also libraries that calculate it, such as GeographicLib and PROJ.

Comment: Ok, so I tried 2 methods one was to use pyproj module and another ws to use a mathematical formula that I found online. I am updating the description with in details of both methods shortly.